# Jekyll build and serve not working on Ubuntu (WSL)

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, jekyll, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to run `bundle exec jekyll serve` on my project with Ubuntu (WSL) on Windows 11, but I keep getting the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        40: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
        39: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
        38: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.13/exe/bundle:36:in `<top (required)>'
        37: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.13/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:103:in `with_friendly_errors'
        36: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.13/exe/bundle:48:in `block in <top (required)>'
        35: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.13/lib/bundler/cli.rb:25:in `start'
        34: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.13/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
        33: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.13/lib/bundler/cli.rb:31:in `dispatch'
        32: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.13/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        31: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.13/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        30: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.13/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        29: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.13/lib/bundler/cli.rb:483:in `exec'
        28: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.13/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:23:in `run'
        27: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.13/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `kernel_load'
        26: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.13/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `load'
        25: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/bin/jekyll:23:in `<top (required)>'
        24: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
        23: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
        22: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary.rb:21:in `program'
        21: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/program.rb:44:in `go'
        20: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `execute'
        19: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `each'
        18: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `block in execute'
        17: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
        16: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `process_with_graceful_fail'
        15: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `each'
        14: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `block in process_with_graceful_fail'
        13: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:36:in `process'
        12: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:65:in `build'
        11: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/command.rb:28:in `process_site'
        10: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:82:in `process'
         9: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:230:in `write'
         8: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:356:in `each_site_file'
         7: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:356:in `each'
         6: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:357:in `block in each_site_file'
         5: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:357:in `each'
         4: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:358:in `block (2 levels) in each_site_file'
         3: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:231:in `block in write'
         2: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/static_file.rb:110:in `write'
         1: from /home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/static_file.rb:204:in `copy_file'
/home/davyk17/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/static_file.rb:204:in `utime': Operation not permitted @ apply2files - /mnt/c/Users/davyk/Documents/Web development/explore.batterywholesale.com/_site/assets/custom.css (Errno::EPERM)
```

I initially thought it was a permission issue that could be solved with `sudo chmod` and `sudo chown` but those haven't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it was a permissions issue after all. I gave my user account on my Windows PC administrator privileges, ran VS Code as an administrator and `bundle exec jekyll serve` started working again.